# switching the browser AIR apps open links in on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, browser, adobe-air

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10, and my default browser is Google Chrome. However, Adobe Air apps always open links in Firefox for some reason. Both DestroyTwitter and TweetDeck do it. Does anyone know how to switch which browser these apps (DT preferably) will open links in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under **System -> Preferences -> Main Menu**, you can change the command that will launch the application. To make TweetDeck use your default browser for example, you'd use this:

```
bash -c "export GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=Default; /opt/air/TweetDeck/bin/TweetDeck"
```